# Regular expression to match numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a regular expression `regex` to match one of these patterns:

- Number followed by `x`
- Number separated by one or more space

I don't know if `match` is the correct method to achieve the results.

Matching examples:

```
' 30x '
'30x'
'20 30'
' 20 30 '

'30x'.match(regex).to_a #=> ['30']
'30 40'.match(regex).to_a #=> ['30', '40']
"30".match(regex).to_a # => ["30"]
" 30 ".match(regex).to_a # => ["30"]
"30 40".match(regex).to_a # => ["30", "40"]
```

Non-matching examples:

```
'20x 30 '
'x20 '

"30xx".match(regex).to_a # => nil
"30 a".match(regex).to_a # => nil
"30 60x".match(regex).to_a # => nil
"30x 20".match(regex).to_a # => nil
```

**EDIT**

Following @TeroTilus advice, this is the use case for this question:

The user will insert how he will pay an debt. Then, we've created a textfield to
easily insert the payment condition. Example:

```
 > "15 20" # Generate 2 bills: First for 15 days and second for 20 days
 > "2x" # Generate 2 bills: First for 30 days and second for 60 days 
 > "2x 30" # Show message of 'Invalid Format'
 > "ANY other string" # Show message of 'Invalid Format'
```

Comment: if you are trying to parse a css file, maybe you should use a parser instead.

Comment: @fotanus I'm not trying to parse a css file.

Comment: Do you have to do it in a single test?  It's much easier and more readable to handle your two cases seperately.  - Or rather, to identify your first case "a single number followed by x" and remove the x, thus causing the result to match your second case.

Comment: Oh man! This is no place for a regex. Put a little more effort on the UI to assist the user.  Maybe something to choose the count of repayments and then default timings that the user can adjust if she wishes.  Or something totally different that suits your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
/^\s*\d+(?:x\s*|\s*\d+)?$/
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\s*\d+(?:x\s*|\s*\d+)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    x                        'x'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.scan(/(^|\s+)(\d+)x?/).map(&:last)`, it probably does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but `"20x 30".scan(/(^|\s+)(\d+)x?/).map(&:last)` returns `["20", "30"]`. but it should returns `nil`.

Comment: Ah, you mean either sequence of digits followed by "x" or exactly two sequences of digits separated (and optionally surrounded) by space?  Would that be the case?  A little more use case context would definitely clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the examples you gave.

`^(?:\s*(\d+))+x?\s*$`

```
^     # Match start of string
(?:   # Open non-capturing group
\s*   # Zero or more spaces at start or between numbers
(\d+) # Capture one or more numbers
)     # Close the group
+     # Group should appear one or more times
x?    # The final group may have an x directly after it
\s*   # Zero or more trailing spaces are allowed
$     # Match the end of the string
```

Edited to capture the numbers, not sure if you were looking to do this or just match the string.

Comment: I want to know if string match one of patterns, if yes, I need get the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

`\d*x\s*$|\d*[^x] \d[^\s]*`

Comment: `"30x".match(/\d*x\s*$|\d*[^x] \d[^\s]*/).to_a #=> ["30x"]` and should be `30`

Answer (score 0):

I have newer written a single line of ruby so the syntax of the below might be horible

But, the easiest solution to your problem is; first reduce your first case to your second case, then do your matching for numbers.

Something like;

```
("20x 30".gsub/^\s*(\d+)x\s*$/,'\1').match(/\b\d+\b/)
```